# Add values from an ng-repeat to a sum

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, html-table

So I have a table with data on the rows and I want to have on the last column the sum of them like here:

```
a   b   c   d   total
1   1   1   1     4
3   1   3   8    15
0   4   0   1     5
```

this is how the body of the table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.tableData[0] track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="label in $ctrl.xTableAxis">{{$ctrl.tableData[$index][$parent.$index].toFixed(2)}}</td>
        <td>show the sum here</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The values are here: `$ctrl.tableData[$index][$parent.$index].toFixed(2)`, the problem is how to add them the print into the next `<td>`.

Is there a way to add the values inside the body?

Comment: use if perhaps? check your index if its already max then show sum else not on your td?

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested methodology cannot be done in an elegant way in ng-repeat (which is allready ugly enough by itself).

The right way to do it would be using a simple reduce function.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.tableData[0] track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="label in $ctrl.xTableAxis">{{$ctrl.tableData[$index][$parent.$index].toFixed(2)}}</td>
        <td>{{ $ctrl.tableData[$index].reduce((a,b)=>a+b)}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Edit:

In case you get a syntax error you can do the following:

In template:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.tableData[0] track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="label in $ctrl.xTableAxis">{{$ctrl.tableData[$index][$parent.$index].toFixed(2)}}</td>
        <td>{{ $ctrl.tableData[$index].reduce(add)}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.add = (a,b)=>a+b
```

Comment: tried it, gives this error message: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 34 of the expression [$ctrl.tableData[$index].reduce((a,b)=>a+b)] starting at [,b)=>a+b)].`

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddles hope it helps

http://jsfiddle.net/hjk5evv2/

js:

```
angular.module('app',['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.items = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];
$scope.sum = function(array){
return array.reduce(add, 0);
}

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
})
```

html:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    {{ctrlTest}}<hr/>Ng-Repeat<hr/>

  <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
    <td ng-repeat="y in x">{{ y }}</td>
    <td>{{ sum(x) }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```